# Why can I use handleClick function in here?

Tags: javascript

The method handleClick is defined in obj, why can I use it in the button's click event?

```js
var obj = {
  name: "test",
  clickBtn: function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  },
  handleClick: function() {
    console.dir(this);
  }
}
obj.clickBtn();
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: What is the error? It seems to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/w21g9hss/

Comment: Are you asking "Why CAN  I use it, because I should not be able to" or are you asking "Why CAN'T I use it" which is strange, because you are

Comment: @mplungjan I thought ‘this’ in ‘this.handleClick’refers to btn, but the method handleClick is defined in obj. So why can I use it? I thought I should not be able to use it.

Comment: The `this` in this.handleClick is the object you created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` has two different contexts in your piece of code.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
```

In the function declaration, the context for `this` is the parent object, `obj`. Here `this.handleClick` refers to `obj.handleClick`.

When the code is executed, the context of `this` within `handleClick` is the object on which the click event handler is executed, so `btn` in this case. In the previous line of code, `btn` is declared as a reference to the HTML element with the `id` property value 'btn'.

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: I changed the previous code to this  :   `btn.addEventListener('click',console.dir(this));`   And it will print obj in the console even I do not click this button. What happened in this situation?

Comment: 'this' is javascript refers to the current execution context. As rightly pointed out by @Dan 'this' - during the creation of the object it is pointing to the obj itself as it is the current execution context, this is similar to calling a constructor function using 'new' keyword. So 'this' holding the handle click function is attached to the button object. So when that executes the 'handleclick' attached to button object is invoked and since it the current execution context now the 'this' would print the button object.

Answer (score 0):

It is because at the very end you have this code `obj.clickBtn();`

`obj.clickBtn();` will basically `call` the `clickBtn` function which will in turn assign a click listener to the button. 
Consecutively the `handleClick` method will be called whenever the click event is raised.

Remove that code and it will not work. In that case you will have to add the listener yourself whenever you want to handle a click event on the button.